# overflow:hidden и абсолютное позиционирование

Tags: css

Задача скрыть блоки по горизонтали (с появлением scroll), которые не помещаются по ширине.
У блоков есть псевдоэлемент ::before с position: absolute. Так вот при свойстве overflow-x: scroll эти элементы обрезаются сверху. А нужно что бы они были видны.

```css
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none; /* Убираем исходные маркеры */
  counter-reset: num; /* Задаём имя счетчика */
  width: 100px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow-y:visible;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-right: 5px;
 
  
}
   li::before {
    content: counter(num) ' '; /* Выводим число */
    counter-increment: num; /* Увеличиваем значение         счётчика */
    color: black;
    font-style: bold;
     font-size: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top:-15px;
     
   }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}

ul {
  margin: -15px 0 0 0;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
  list-style-type: none; /* Убираем исходные маркеры */
  counter-reset: num; /* Задаём имя счетчика */
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-y:visible;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-right: 5px;
}

li::before {
  content: counter(num) ' '; /* Выводим число */
  counter-increment: num; /* Увеличиваем значение         счётчика */
  color: black;
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top:-15px;
}
```

```html
Some text goes here...
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
Some text goes here...
```

Comment: За счёт падингов показываем числа?

Comment: @Григорий, да. Можно ещё с z-index'ами поиграться, но не думаю, что по задумке эти числа на что-то ещё полезное накладываются.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде исправил...

Как догадался - не знаю. Решил просто убрать `position: absolute` из `li::before` и вроде сработало.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none; /* Убираем исходные маркеры */
  counter-reset: num; /* Задаём имя счетчика */
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow-y:visible;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); 
}

li::before {
  content: counter(num) ' '; /* Выводим число */
  counter-increment: num; /* Увеличиваем значение         счётчика */
  color: black;
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 5px;       /* сдвиг цифры по горизонтали */
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да, без absolute все работает. В этом то и дело, что требуется сохранить абсолютное позиционирование )

Comment: @Григорий Этот самый абсолют все портит...